# PHP's json extension is required to use Monolog's NormalizerFormatter

Tags: php, json, symfony

I'am new to symfony. I have created symfony project using:
symfony new PhpSymfony // command.
when i run project using:
php bin/console server:run // command, app.php page is displayed in the browser (http://localhost:8000).
But if I run without using the command php bin/console server:run,
I will get an exception in the browser

"RuntimeException in classes.php line 5493: PHP's json extension is required to use Monolog's NormalizerFormatter"

I am running on http://localhost/app_dev.php
and I a using apache2 server... 
How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install PHP and required PHP extensions.

Install PHP JSON extension for *nix/Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

Depending of Symfony version, you need to enable list of extensions (for Symfony 2.8.*):

1. PHP needs to be a minimum version of PHP 5.3.9.
2. JSON needs to be enabled.
3. ctype needs to be enabled.
4. Your php.ini needs to have the date.timezone setting.

[Requirements for Running Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/requirements.html)

Also, you need to [set up Web-server.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)

More information about setting up Symfony project [here.](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/setup.html)